# Excel Compare two rows

Tags: excel

[image]

I have to compare column having same values but not in the same order. 
I want to pick the first value in the first column and then find it in the second column.

If I find it then I want to copy it in the third column with the number of records.

I want to repeat this exercise for every value in the first column.

Comment: I think this might help you http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/hlookup-HP005209114.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called `VLOOKUP()` and is a built-in function of Excel that will do it exactly for you. You can read more about `VLOOKUP()` [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx). Examples have also been provided.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that the first column is **A** and the second column is **D** (based on your picture) and you want the number of records displayed on column **E**. In this case you should set the following formulas on **E1, E2,...** cells:

`E1 ----> =COUNTIF(D:D, A1)`

`E2 ----> =COUNTIF(D:D, A2)...`